# Newlines while saving variable to file - bash

Tags: bash

I have mulitiple ip adresses in a variable.

```
ActiveIPs=192.168.0.1 192.168.0.2 192.168.0.3
```

I want to save them to a file like this seperated by a newline

```
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
```

how do i do this?

Comment: There must be a typo. There's no way the first character of that expansion could be a space unless you wrap it in quotes.

Comment: You still have to *quote* the entire string; otherwise, anything from the 2nd token is interpreted as a *command* (at least in bash 3.2.48).

Answer (score 2):

```
$ ActiveIPs="192.168.0.1 192.168.0.2 192.168.0.3"

$ awk '1' RS=' ' <<< "$ActiveIPs"
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
```

Comment: Nice; the `RS` (input record separator) technique is good to know. One caveat: with `<<<` you'll get an extra trailing `\n` in the output; to avoid that, use `printf "$ActiveIPs" | awk '1' RS=' '`.

Answer (score 1):

`printf` will repeat a pattern as necessary.

```
ActiveIPs="192.168.0.1 192.168.0.2 192.168.0.3"
printf "%s\n" $ActiveIPs > file.txt
```

Comment: I'm giving +1 to all the answers that don't involve pipelines or external commands.

Comment: This is a great solution for the specific input value, but it's tricky for general use: the solution relies on the value to be subject to *expansion* by the shell, which can have unwanted side effects.

Answer (score 1):

```
for ip in $ActiveIPs; do
    echo $ip >> file
done
```

Comment: (Although it's more efficient to just put `> file` at the end of the loop to write it once rather than appending each line separately.)

Answer (score 1):

Use a parameter expansion to change all space characters to newlines:

```
$ foo='abc def ghi'
$ echo "${foo// /$'\n'}"
abc
def
ghi
```

Using a parameter expansion avoids creating a new process altogether, not even a builtin command.

If you can, you'd be better off saving the values into an array:

```
$ input=( 192.168.0.100 10.0.0.1 192.168.0.101 )
```

This way, you have complete control over how the shell splits the words, and you still don't have to invoke an external command.

```
$ SAVE_IFS="$IFS"
$ IFS=$'\n'
$ echo "${input[*]}"
192.168.0.100
10.0.0.1
192.168.0.101
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too basic, but this works:

```
echo "ActiveIPs= 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.2 192.168.0.3" | cut -d= -f2 | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}'
```

Output:

```
192.168.0.1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
192.168.0.2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
192.168.0.3
```

**To everyone**: is there a better way to print a new line between each field in `awk`? Tried with `OFS='\n'` but did not work.

Comment: To answer your question `echo "ActiveIPs= 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.2 192.168.0.3" | awk 'NR>1' RS=' '` however I don't think `ActiveIPs` in contain in text it's the variable name see my answer.

Comment: Oh, did not know about `RS`. I thought its purpose was done by `OF` (what's their difference?). Also: now I see your point about `ActiveIPs=...`, I thought it was a whole string. +1 for your answer, @sudo_O.

Comment: A field is built up of records, a record is built up of fields, `awk` iterates over records (by default a record is a newline). By defining what the records are `awk` will do the iteration so you don't have to.  To understand why setting `OFS` didn't work for your read http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/ specially the self-assignment section.

Comment: Just read a little bit of the site you indicate and looks very juicy stuff to read this weekend. Thanks for it, @sudo_O! Will come back on Monday with new questions : )

Answer (score 0):

Note - Immediately after the `\` hit newline-:

```
echo $ActiveIPs | sed 's/ /\
/g'
```

Comment: Here's a single-line version using the `$'\n'` literal: `echo $ActiveIPs | sed 's/ /\'$'\n''/g'`