# How to increment array dynamically with 'awk'?

Tags: arrays, linux, awk

I have file that contains list of IPs:

```
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
5.5.5.5
1.1.1.1
5.5.5.5
```

I want to create file that prints list of counters of above mentioned IPs like:

```
1.1.1.1: 2
2.2.2.2: 1
3.3.3.3: 1
5.5.5.5: 2
```

Where 2,1,1,2 are counters.

I started to write script that work for final count IPs and known count but don't know how to continue

```
 ./ff.sh file_with_IPs.txt
```

**script**

```
#!/bin/sh

file=$1

awk  '
BEGIN {
    for(x=0; x<4; ++x)
        count[x] = 0;

 ip[0] = "1.1.1.1";
 ip[1] = "2.2.2.2";
 ip[2] = "3.3.3.3";
 ip[3] = "5.5.5.5";    
}
{
    if($1==ip[0]){
       count[0] += 1;
     } else if($1==ip[1]){
       count[1] += 1;
     }else if($1==ip[2]){
       count[2] += 1;
     }else if($1==ip[3]){
       count[3] += 1;
     }
}
END {
    for(x=0; x<4; ++x) {
       print ip[x] ": " count[x]
    }
}
' $file > newfile.txt
```

The main problem that I don't know how many IPs stored in file and how they look like.

So I need to increment array `ip` each time when awk catch new IP.

Comment: Have you considered using `uniq` instead? Or is there some reason you want to stay in awk?

Comment: i run on list of files and files contain not only ips (other garbage as well). With `awk` I can fetch ip as value

Comment: but you welcome to post your answer with `uniq` if you know how :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is quite easier with `sort -u`, but with awk this can do it:

```
awk '{a[$0]++; next}END {for (i in a) print i": "a[i]}' file_with_IPs.txt
```

Output:

```
1.1.1.1: 2
3.3.3.3: 1
5.5.5.5: 2
2.2.2.2: 1
```

(with a little help of [this tutorial](http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/) that [sudo_O recommended me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16103804/newlines-while-saving-variable-to-file-bash/16103878#comment22996188_16103878))

Comment: "next" is not necessary here.

Comment: Uhms, I see - as we are not performing anything else before END, this statement would go to the next record anyway. I will leave it like it is, not to have the exact answer as Zsolt. Anyway, thanks for letting me now, @Kent.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `uniq` for that task, like:

```
sort IPFILE | uniq -c
```

(Note, that this prints the occurrences in front of the IP.)

Or with awk (if there are only IP addresses on the lines):

```
awk '{ips[$0]++} END { for (k in ips) { print k, ips[k] } }' IPFILE
```

(Note, this prints the IP addresses unordered, but you can do it with awk, read the docs, for `asort`, `asorti`, or simply append a `sort` after a pipe. )

Comment: It is funny to see we coded nearly the same in the same moment. Just changed the name of variables!